# Solr multiple source indexing

Tags: solr

I have 3-4 different data sources (large) here to be indexed in solr with having common properties to be indexed such as content name & content source. What would be the best approach here?

1. Having single collection with all indexes with additional property added for source identification? or
2. Having individual collections for each of sources but all collections having same properties for indexing?

Which of these would be more performant & easier to maintain?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Things to check -

How are the queries going to be - searching across all sources or each search is specific to a source?

Do you have to join on the different sources?

Remember - relevance aspect of the results.

Once you answer these questions, better suggestions are possible.